# 3x3 pay off matrix with no dominated strategy with nash eq

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Create a $3x3$ pay off matrix that does not have any dominated strategy and has exactly two Nash equilibrium. No mixed-strategy is allowed. I have tried and made this

$\begin{bmatrix}
  A    &B   & C\\
1,1 & 0,-1 &-1,0\\
1,-2 & 1,1 &-2,0\\
0,0& 1,-2& 0,-1\\
\end{bmatrix}$

but i am not sure. I am right or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you limit the exercise to pure strategies you are right. But remember to name the strategies of Player $1$ in your matrix. Assuming that they are named $A^{\prime},B^{\prime},C^{\prime}$ from top to bottom, you have two Nash Equilibria in pure strategies: $(A^{\prime},A)$ and $(B^{\prime},B)$, yielding payoffs $(1,1)$ in both cases.

When it comes to domination, no pure strategy dominates another --I haven't checked if there is any mixed strategy that dominates a pure, although at a first glance I would say there is none. In any case, it should be easy to verify.